# What is the reason behind this circuit's behavior when the switches are in different states?

Tags: circuit-analysis, led, current, switches

Just started studying robotics and we were given a couple off tasks without proposed solutions. This is one of them:

> A switch in off-state will be called 0 and the on-state will be called 1. So \$S_1\$ on the circuit below would have the state 0 since the switch is off. Test which combinations of switch-states makes the different lEDs glow and explain why. The battery is 9V and the resistor is 330 ohm.

[image: circuit diagram]

Before testing this we were supposed to guess which switch-state combinations would make the LED(s) glow. A glowing LED would have the state 1 and a non-glowing LED would have the state 0. So I filled in the table bellow before testing.

| \$S_1\$ | \$S_2\$ | \$D_1\$ | \$D_2\$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

All the combinations with \$S_1\$ = 0 would create an incomplete circuit and therefore neither of the LEDs would glow. Then I guessed \$S_1\$ = 1 and \$S_2 = 0\$ would make both LEDs glow since it would allow current to flow through both of them without a problem. Then I guessed \$S_1 = S_2 = 1\$ would make neither of the LEDs glow. My explanation was as follows: Both the LEDs have some resistance while the switches have no resistance (in an ideal circuit). Since there is lower resistance in the path going through \$S_1\$ and \$S_2\$ and none of the LEDs, the current will take this path and the LEDs will therefore not glow.

[image: Screenshot off the circuit I made]

I then checked my answers using an online circuit schematic drawer (Falstad circuits) and my answer in terms of the combinations was correct. But I dont know if my reasoning/explanation was correct.

Could someone tell me if this was the correct way to think? If not, what have I done wrong and what is the correct way to explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Does Mathjax not work on electrical engineering exchange? [This documentaion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) showed that using the $$ would allow me to create math formulas.

Comment: Use backslash dollarsign.

Comment: Mathjax works differently on this site, because, apparently, engineers sprinkle $ signs around that they'd like to stay as $. Use backslash$ instead. I've fixed the first few for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I fixed the rest now.

Comment: @volticus - Hi, Regarding MathJax - you linked to documentation about MathJax on Math.SE's Meta. Here are links to some relevant posts on *our* Meta, explaining why the earlier MathJax $ delimiter was causing problems here, since prices (with $) get mentioned (not so much on Math.SE) - see [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6427) & [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/440). As others kindly commented, `\$` is the *inline* MathJax delimiter here, and `$$` is the *block* MathJax delimiter here (like it is elsewhere on SE, inc Math.SE AFAIK). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is mostly correct. Only

> Since there is lower resistance in the path going through \$S_1\$ and \$S_2\$
> and none of the LEDs, the current will take this path and the LEDs
> will therefore not glow.

is a bit imprecise. If a current gets "offered" two paths, in general it will not **completely** take the lower-resistance path, but split across the paths (proportional to the reciprokes of the resistances). But in your case, the \$S_2\$ has a zero resistance, so it gets all of the current.

Answer (score 0):

You reasoning looks fine to me. For a more formal approach, consider the voltage at each node in the circuit in the different cases, and voltage differences across components, remembering that if two nodes have just wire between them, they will be at the same potential.

In particular, make sure you understand how in the (1,1) case, the resistor is connected straight across the battery, which means there is no voltage across the LEDs so they cannot light.

Comment: I'll add that this is an ideal case, and in a real world situation, the result in the (1,0) case might be different depending on the actual properties of each LED. If one has a clearly smaller voltage drop, the larger one won't light because the smaller one makes the voltage across both of them too small.